# Data table with json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I want to create a datatable using a JSON array, and its work fine but my problem is I want to change the last column value with a custome value. How to solve this problem?

This is my code.

```
    var val=[{"PhoneNumber":"9961196748","CallType":"Outgoing","DialedTime":"2018-09-11 09:39:52","ConnectedTime":"2018-09-11 09:40:12","DisconnectedTime":"2018-09-11 09:40:27","CallDuration":"0:35 minutes","CallSummary":"Dialled/Connected/Disconnected","Action":38},{"PhoneNumber":"9961196748","CallType":"Outgoing","DialedTime":"2018-09-11 10:06:57","ConnectedTime":"2018-09-11 10:07:15","DisconnectedTime":"2018-09-11 10:07:24","CallDuration":"0:27 minutes","CallSummary":"Dialled/Connected/Disconnected","Action":39}]
    var test='<button class="btn"  ><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>';

    $('#datatable-individualreportmodal').DataTable ({
        "data" : val,
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "PhoneNumber" },
            { "data" : "CallType" },
            { "data" : "DialedTime" },
            { "data" : "ConnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "DisconnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "CallDuration" },
            { "data" : "CallSummary" },
            { "data" : test }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: What is val here. Can you show output of val?

Comment: @CodeThing : I updated the question with value of val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your val variable and then change Action value.

```
var test='<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>';

$.each(val, function(key, index) {
    index.Action = test;
});

//Parse and apply in datatable

$('#datatable-individualreportmodal').DataTable ({
        "data" : val,
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "PhoneNumber" },
            { "data" : "CallType" },
            { "data" : "DialedTime" },
            { "data" : "ConnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "DisconnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "CallDuration" },
            { "data" : "CallSummary" },
            { "data" : "Action" }
        ]
    });
```

To Add some style to particular row, we can do something like the below.
I don't know if its a proper way or not, but this should do a trick

```
$('#datatable-individualreportmodal').DataTable ({
        "data" : val,
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "PhoneNumber" },
            { "data" : "CallType" },
            { "data" : "DialedTime" },
            { "data" : "ConnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "DisconnectedTime" },
            { "data" : "CallDuration" },
            { "data" : "CallSummary" },
            { "data" : "Action" }
        ],
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            var callDuration = data.CallDuration.replace(':', '.');
            callDuration = callDuration.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
          if ( parseFloat(callDuration) <= 0 ) {
            $(row).addClass('highlight');
          }
        }
    });
```

This should apply called called `highlight` to the row which is having less than call time.

Comment: Thanks, its working. and one more doubt, how to add style in specific rows ? for example value of CallDuration is 0 then I want to add some style into that row.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ColumnDef property

```
"columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return data;
                        },
                        "targets": 0
                    },
]
```

Please refer the link [https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data](http://Column%20data)